# moving pivot point of an object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, point, gameobject

This is the object I am trying to move the pivot of:

[image]

I am currently trying to move the pivot point of this object to the center, since i need it to be centered there for a script i am making, does anybody have any idea how to do this? as I have no idea what I need to do or how. I just spent a decent amount of time creating this and making it do what i need it to, everything is perfect but I really need the pivot point to be in the centre, so if possible i would like to do this in unity to avoid having to redo the entire thing.

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: It seems that the pivot is wrong in the model. It is easier to change it in the 3D modelling software.

Comment: Or you make it a child of another empty object so the pivot is in the middle

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Just make the object a child of an empty gameobject and move that one

There is no way of changing the pivot point of a model directly in unity since it's technically just the general position of the vertices and modifying geometry isn't the job of the unity editor. However one way of changing the pivot is just making the object a child of another and using that one's position. There are also some tools for this in the assetstore. (including free ones) Of course you could also just change the pivot point in the 3d modelling program of your choice.